# When does hibernate close a cursor?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Recently I'm working on a Spring+Hibernate project, with Oracle. I find out there are always hundreds of cursors opened at the same time.
I have no clew to solve this problem. Can anyone give me some suggestions? or some references?

PS:I know it's not a very good question, but I found it's hard to search for an accurate document, and I don't have time to work through all hibernate documents currently.

PS2: I used a lot of  criteria and normal select query in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Hibernate 4.3.0.Final you probably experience known hibernate bug:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8811

As you can see from link, this bug causes too many opened cursors.

Switching to version 4.3.1.Final solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to take care of closing the cursors. Thumb rule is if you open a cursor then after processing result set you must close it else you are unnecessarily occupying resources.

Check this discussion, it shows how it works : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1041031921901